# Bison doesn't use the right yylex arguments

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to learn how to build a C++ based Lexer/Parser, I'm following multiple tutorials and guides online, my code is mostly built off of those two guides: [1](http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/FlexBisonC++), [2](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/A-Complete-C_002b_002b-Example.html) although I added and tweaked as I saw fit.

First, I had a header file for the lexer:

```
#ifndef SHELL_VARIABLELEXER_HPP
#define SHELL_VARIABLELEXER_HPP

#if ! defined(yyFlexLexerOnce)
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#endif

#include "ShellVariableParser.hpp"
#include "location.hh"

namespace SHELL
{
    /// This overloads the yyFlexLexer class
    class ShellVariableLexer : public yyFlexLexer
    {
        private:
           /// a yylval pointer
           ShellVariableParser::semantic_type *yylval = nullptr;
           /// a ocation pointer
           ShellVariableParser::location_type *loc    = nullptr;
        public:
            /// This constructor only creates the location type.
            ShellVariableLexer(std::istream *in) : yyFlexLexer(in)
            {
                loc = new ShellVariableParser::location_type();
            }

            using FlexLexer::yylex;

            /// A declaration for the yylex function, errors if not here!
            virtual ShellVariableParser::symbol_type yylex(ShellVariableParser::semantic_type* const lval, ShellVariableParser::location_type* location);
    };
}

#endif // ShellVariableLEXER_HPP
```

Then I defined my .l file, which build fine through flex and g++:

```
%{    
#include <string>
#include "Shell/ShellVariableLexer.hpp"

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL SHELL::ShellVariableParser::symbol_type SHELL::ShellVariableLexer::yylex(SHELL::ShellVariableParser::semantic_type * const lval, SHELL::ShellVariableParser::location_type *location)
#define yyterminate() return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_END(*loc)
#define YY_USER_ACTION loc->step(); loc->columns(yyleng);

%}

%option yylineno
%option yyclass="SHELL::ShellVariableLexer"
%option outfile="src/Shell/ShellVariableLexer.cpp"
%option noyywrap
%option c++

%%
%{
    yylval = lval;
%}

[0-9]+\.[0-9]+          {
                            std::string Tmp(yytext, yyleng);
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_FLOAT(std::stod(Tmp, NULL), *loc);
                        }
[0-9]+                  {
                            std::string Tmp(yytext, yyleng);
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_INTEGER(std::stoi(Tmp, NULL), *loc);
                        }
"$"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_DOLLARSIGN(*loc);
"{"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_LBRACE(*loc);
"}"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_RBRACE(*loc);
"+"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_PLUS(*loc);
"-"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_MINUS(*loc);
"*"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_MULTIPLY(*loc);
"/"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_DIVIDE(*loc);
"("                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_LPARAN(*loc);
")"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_RPARAN(*loc);
"\""                    return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_DQUOTE(*loc);
(?i:ON)                 return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_ON(*loc);
(?i:OFF)                return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_OFF(*loc);
(?i:TRUE)               return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_TRUE(*loc);
(?i:FALSE)              return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_FALSE(*loc);
[ \t]
[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]+  {
                            std::string Tmp(yytext, yyleng);
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_VARIABLE(Tmp, *loc);
                        }
[0-9a-zA-Z_ :/\t]+      {
                            std::string Tmp(yytext, yyleng);
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::make_STRING(Tmp, *loc);
                        }

%%
```

I then created my .y file, the file goes through bison OK, but fails when compiled using g++, I will not show the whole file here, just the first part, the rules are irrelevant for my error anyway:

```
%defines "include/Shell/ShellVariableParser.hpp"
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%define api.namespace {SHELL}
%define parser_class_name {ShellVariableParser}
%output "src/Shell/ShellVariableParser.cpp"
%define api.value.type variant
%define api.token.constructor
%define parse.assert
// %lex-param {semantic_type* const yylval}
// %lex-param {location_type* location}

%code requires
{    
    #include <utility>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    #include "ShellVariables.hpp"
    #include "Util/IO.hpp"

    namespace SHELL
    {
        class ShellVariableLexer;
    }

// The following definitions is missing when %locations isn't used
# ifndef YY_NULLPTR
#  if defined __cplusplus && 201103L <= __cplusplus
#   define YY_NULLPTR nullptr
#  else
#   define YY_NULLPTR 0
#  endif
# endif
}

%parse-param {ShellVariableLexer &lexer}
%define parse.trace
%define parse.error verbose

%code
{
#include "ShellVariableLexer.hpp"
#undef yylex
#define yylex lexer.yylex
}

%token<double>              FLOAT
%token<int64_t>             INTEGER
%token<std::string>         STRING
%token<std::string>         VARIABLE
%token                      DOLLARSIGN
%token                      LBRACE
%token                      RBRACE
%token                      PLUS
%token                      MINUS
%token                      MULTIPLY
%token                      DIVIDE
%token                      LPARAN
%token                      RPARAN
%token                      DQUOTE
%token                      ON
%token                      OFF
%token                      TRUE
%token                      FALSE
%token                      END

%locations

%type   <std::pair<uint8_t,VariableType>> All;
%type   <std::pair<uint8_t,VariableType>> Bool;
%type   <std::pair<uint8_t,VariableType>> Integer;
%type   <std::pair<uint8_t,VariableType>> Float;
%type   <std::pair<uint8_t,VariableType>> String;
%type   <std::string> __string__;
%type   <VariableType> variable;

%%
```

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
src/Shell/ShellVariableParser.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int SHELL::ShellVariableParser::parse()’:
src/Shell/ShellVariableParser.cpp:494:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘SHELL::ShellVariableParser::basic_symbol<SHELL::ShellVariableParser::by_type>::basic_symbol(int)’
             symbol_type yylookahead (yylex ());
```

According to this [link](http://www.manpagez.com/info/bison/bison-2.3/bison_117.php#SEC117) I expected the yylex function generated by bison to be the same as the one defined in the lexer header file. But this is not the case. If I try and manually add those parameters by uncommenting the two `%lex-param` lines from the .y file, I get the following error:

```
src/Shell/ShellVariableParser.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int SHELL::ShellVariableParser::parse()’:
src/Shell/ShellVariableParser.cpp:494:45: error: ‘yylval’ was not declared in this scope
             symbol_type yylookahead (yylex (yylval, location));
```

I'm guessing this might be the right way to do it, except for the variable names `yylval` and `location`? Or am I missing some other options?

I'm using gcc version 6.2.0 with Ubuntu GLIBC 2.24-3ubuntu2, flex version 2.6.1 and bison version 3.0.4.

### EDIT

I still have no idea what is causing this, I tried converting `yylex` in the .l file to return ints, and instead of `make_` I returned the actual tokens:

```
%{
#include <string>
#include "Shell/ShellVariableLexer.hpp"

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int SHELL::ShellVariableLexer::yylex(SHELL::ShellVariableParser::semantic_type * const lval, SHELL::ShellVariableParser::location_type *location)
#define yyterminate() return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::END
#define YY_USER_ACTION loc->step(); loc->columns(yyleng);

%}

%option yylineno
%option yyclass="SHELL::ShellVariableLexer"
%option outfile="src/Shell/ShellVariableLexer.cpp"
%option noyywrap
%option c++

%%
%{
    yylval = lval;
%}

[0-9]+\.[0-9]+          {
                            std::string Tmp(yytext, yyleng);
                            yylval->build<double>(std::stod(Tmp));
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::FLOAT;
                        }
[0-9]+                  {
                            std::string Tmp(yytext, yyleng);
                            yylval->build<int64_t>(std::stoi(Tmp));
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::INTEGER;
                        }
"$"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::DOLLARSIGN;
"{"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::LBRACE;
"}"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::RBRACE;
"+"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::PLUS;
"-"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::MINUS;
"*"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::MULTIPLY;
"/"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::DIVIDE;
"("                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::LPARAN;
")"                     return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::RPARAN;
"\""                    return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::DQUOTE;
(?i:ON)                 return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::ON;
(?i:OFF)                return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::OFF;
(?i:TRUE)               return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::TRUE;
(?i:FALSE)              return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::FALSE;
[ \t]
[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]+  {
                            yylval->build<std::string>(yytext);
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::VARIABLE;
                        }
[0-9a-zA-Z_ :/\t]+      {
                            yylval->build<std::string>(yytext);
                            return SHELL::ShellVariableParser::token::STRING;
                        }
%%
```

in the bison file I just removed the `%define api.token.constructor` line and the two `%lex-param` lines. It works fine.

So basically all I did was change the return type of yylex, not its arguments! why on earth is this working but the first implementation doesn't? why is the `return int` working but the `return symbol_type` does not?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misreading the C++ error message. The compiler is not complaining about the arguments to `yylex`. The error message (with `SHELL::ShellVariableParser` condensed for readability) says:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 
‘SH...er::basic_symbol<SH...er::by_type>::basic_symbol(int)’
         symbol_type yylookahead (yylex ());
```

In fact, `symbol_type` is a type alias for `SHELL::ShellVariableParser::basic_symbol<SHELL::ShellVariableParser::by_type>`, so an even more readable rendering would be

```
error: no matching function for call to ’symbol_type::symbol_type(int)’
```

In other words, `yylex()` returns an `int`, but since `symbol_type` has no constructor which takes an `int`, the declaration of `yylookahead` is invalid.

So the problem is the *return type* of `yylex`, which you presumably intended to be `symbol_type`.

Unfortunately, the (in my opinion clunky) flex C++ interface is working against you. In the base class `FlexLexer`, `yylex()` is declared as a virtual function which returns `int`. Since your ShellVariableLexer is derived from `FlexLexer`, you cannot define `yylex()` as returning a different type.

You could, of course, add an unnecessary argument, which is more or less what your declaration of `ShellVariableParser::yylex` does:

```
virtual ShellVariableParser::symbol_type yylex(ShellVariableParser::semantic_type* const lval, ShellVariableParser::location_type* location);
```

But since the parameters are only necessary to avoid confusing the method with the one declared in the base class, you could use something simpler, like:

```
ShellVariableParser::symbol_type yylex(int);
```

and then arrange for it to be the version called with

```
#define yylex() lexer.yylex(0)
```

(There's not much point declaring that as virtual. The base classes do not have a similar prototype, so the only reason to declare it virtual would be if you were going to subclass `ShellVariableParser`.)

Comment: This advice only works if you have locations disabled, otherwise symbol_type a struct that expects a token_type/int and a location_type.

Comment: @kfsone: and that's what the various `make_TOKEN()` methods return. So what's the problem? (The answer applies to the *first* snippet, not the edit.)